# show result of select from table in silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I'm new to Silverlight. My code works in Window Forms:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        DBConnect dbconnect = new DBConnect();

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\WriteLines4.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(dbconnect.CountPublic());
        }

        dbconnect.CloseConnectionPublic();
    }
```

It connects to database, counts rows in table, writes result into txt file and closes connection.

Now my need is to show result in silverlight (web page) instead of writing into txt file. How do I start?

UPDATE: 
Silverlight doesn't work with database directly. My need is to create WCF service for work with database and consume service using Silverlight. 
Found simple example for SL & WCF to start with: 
http://sonyarouje.com/2010/10/16/image-uploading-retrieving-silverlight-and-wcf/

Comment: you need start from somewhere.... you can start here http://www.silverlight.net/learn